# HowTo select all models based on related model in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE match (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    home_team_id INT,
    away_team_id INT,
    ...
)

CREATE  TABLE scorer (
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   match_id INT,
   player_id INT,
   ....
)
```

In Match model I defined a relation something like this:

```
class Match extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'scorers' => array(
                self::HAS_MANY,
                'Scorer',
                'match_id',
             ),
             ...
        );
    }
}
```

How can I get all Match models that have at least one scorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concern about performance issues you should not use :

```
$matches = Match::model()->with(array('scorers'=>array('joinType'=>'INNER JOIN','together'=>true)))->findAll();
```

Simply because this will fetch, for each match, all corresponding scorers.

If you don't need to get scorers data, you should try to add this in your `Match` model (just an example) :

```
public function findAllHavingScorer()
{
    $matchAlias = $this->tableAlias;
    $scorerTable = Scorer::model()->tableName();

    return $this->findAll(array(
        'condition'=>"EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $scorerTable WHERE $scorerTable.post_id=$matchAlias.id)",
    ));
}
```

After you just have to use this :

```
$matches = Match::model()->findAllHavingScorer();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/46999-show-items-that-have-at-least-one-relation/) on the forum:

```
$matches = Match::model()->with(array('scorers'=>array('joinType'=>'INNER JOIN','together'=>true)))->findAll();
```

It's untested, though it looks right. Give it a bash.

Comment: +1 but you should fix syntax : `$matches = Match::model()->with(array('scorers'=>array('joinType'=>'INNER JOIN','together'=>true)))->findAll();`